# wso2 api manager 1.10 fails to regenerate tokens

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I downloaded and installed WSOAM 1.10 binary and followed steps https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0 for a distributed deployment.  Upon entering the "My Subscriptions" tab in the store, I'm unable to regenerate keys for my subscribed API and get HTTP 400 error.  The Key Mgr logs show:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-07 20:26:14,730] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint} -  Error while creating the Carbon OAuth token request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint}
OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='Missing grant_type parameter value', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:59)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.utils.OAuthUtils.handleOAuthProblemException(OAuthUtils.java:167)
...

I get the same if I use a curl command: 
curl -k -v -d "token=224cd22cd6b4ee622d951c69be34f633&grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic eG9HSnZDS3FYNVNSazV6N3FHZXhhR3VTSWVnYTpzUTQ0QlBmTXRacG1ZNnA3ZUdPejhONVZxMGdh" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http:GATEWAY_HOST/revoke
```

Looks like the revoke API call is missing the "grant_type" parameter.  Is the documentation correct? :  https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Token+API

Comment: yes it seems like you are missing grant type. It typically is either `password` or `refresh_token` but it depends on the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This document is correct. Following are the sample commands to generate the token and revoke the token.

> curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic
>   dkFGR0pLQWliMDVrUW5fX2JJZFgzS1pEaGZvYTo2NDFGWlNtSVJ2anVIU0ozcTYzbHVENXU0Mllh"
>   http://localhost:8280/token
>
> curl -k -v -d "token=77ed4636c08c80fefb6f7aa1ce6987e0" -H
>   "Authorization: Basic
>   dkFGR0pLQWliMDVrUW5fX2JJZFgzS1pEaGZvYTo2NDFGWlNtSVJ2anVIU0ozcTYzbHVENXU0Mllh"
>   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://localhost:8280/token

Based on the stack trace it looks like when you are trying to revoke the token, call goes to the token endpoint which needs the grant type to generate the token. Please check the default APIs in the synapse (wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api) to verify the endpoints are correct.

Comment: So in a distributed environment, the API Mgr Store could revoke a token by making a call to the http://[API Mgr Gateway]:PORT/revoke URL.  Then the Gateway would then use the synapse APIs to make a call to the key manager with URL http://[Key Mgr]:PORT/oauth2/token.  Is this correct?

Comment: Part of your explanation is correct. Store will call revoke end point in gateway. If you check the _RevokeAPI_.xml in synapse which is the revoke API, the call will go to http://[Key Mgr]:PORT/oauth2/revoke. For revoking a token we use revoke endpoint.